# Meaning of ‘feminista’ as used by Josh Lyman in The West Wing?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In Season 1, Episode 03 of *The West Wing*, Josh Lymann calls CJ Cregg a ‘feminista’ at 4’01”:

> You know what? I think I’m really the best judge of what I mean, you paranoid Berkley shiksa feminista!

Does the word have a specific connotation or meaning that ‘feminist’ does not have, as used by Josh or in general? Why might have Josh used this word in particular?

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=feminista

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of the times when that series aired, *feminista* was a mildly derogatory take on *feminist*. It's a portmanteau of *feminist* and terms like '*Sandinista*' that carry radical leftist baggage.

The Josh character was not being as nasty as that description might sound, rather more sarcastic than really biting.